# Xcode Cloud build queued for hours

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

This is my first time working with Xcode Cloud.
I just created a workflow to build my project in Xcode Cloud.
All dependencies are managed through Swift Package Manager with repositories being hosted on publicly accessible URLs.

I had no issues to start the build workflow on Xcode Cloud, but now it has been queued for five hours already.
Is that normal or am I doing something wrong?

I am running Xcode 14.1 (14B47b) on macOS 13.

I checked the console log for Xcode, but could not find any obvious errors. The closest thing is: `found no value for key XcodeCloudSuppressHideVersions in CFPrefsSearchListSource` but I don't think that is related with the build workflow being queued.

I further checked the [Apple Developer Status Page](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) and it seems like Xcode Cloud should be running fine.

Is there another error log for Xcode Cloud maybe?